# CakePHP: How to set variables with multiple level dependancies

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

In my controller I want to set a variable(A) which has a one to many relationship with another model(B) which has a HABTM (has and belongs to many) relationship with ANOTHER model(C).

Currently when I set the variable in the controller I can access the model(B) in the view, but not ITS dependancies (model C):

```
//A's controller...
public function admin_view($id = NULL) {
    $A = $this->A->findById($id);       
    $this->set('A', $A);
}
```

Here's what I see if I dump the variable in the view:

```
//A's admin_view.ctp...
//debug($A);

array(
'A' => array(
    'id' => '1',
    'name' => 'Name',
    'created' => '2013-04-04 15:25:54',
    'modified' => '2013-04-04 15:25:54'
),
'B' => array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'id' => '1',
        'created' => '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
        'modified' => '2013-04-05 10:31:42'
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'id' => '13',
        'created' => '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
        'modified' => '2013-04-05 10:31:42'
```

Is there a way to set the variable such the each "B" will have it's respective Cs included?

Comment: What is your `$recursive` value? Is it set to 2 or lower?

Comment: Good question!! I dont' know what that is, but it sounds like the reason why it's not working the way I want.

Comment: Boom. That was it: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#recursive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html

```
// In your model
var $actsAs = array('Containable');
```

---

```
// In your controller
public function admin_view($id = NULL) {
    $this->A->contain(array('B' => array('C')));
    $A = $this->A->findById($id);       
    $this->set('A', $A);
}
```

That should give you what you need, setting recursive to 2 is the easy way out, but you'll get redundant data if you have other associations.

Comment: Can you clarify the part about redundant data?

Comment: Well, let's say, `A hasMany D`, would you want to pull in D every time when you're just parsing A, B, and C?  Just saying if you have other associations, those will get pulled in as well, containable lets you selectively choose what child models to pull in.

Answer (score 1):

Well then, explaining $recursive and Containable behavior:
[Recursive](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html) is a value between -1 to 2, and basically it tells the model "I want to fetch this record AND all records associated with it" if it's set to 2. If it's -1, then with find or read you only get *that model data*.
[Containable](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html) let's you specify which models/fields-of-other-models you want to fetch (they have to have an association, though).

I've repeated many times I'm not a fan of `$recursive != -1` because I feel it doesn't let you control what data you retrieve and when to do it. I recommend you use

```
class AppModel extends Model {
public $actsAs = array('Containable');
public $recursive = -1;

     //etc 
}
```

in the AppMdel so everything isn't recursive and containable by default (it isn't necessary for the query to work, though). Then, regarding your question, the find query should be like

```
$A = $this->A->find('first', array('conditions'=>array('id'=>$id),
                                   'contain'=>array('B-model'=>array('C-model'))));
```

Comment: @Emerson nun's example is exactly the same except the "contain" array is passed as an argument to the find call.  Also, nuns, containable behavior overrides the recursive functionality if the containment is supplied. (I believe) So, I think you could even omit the property on the class.

Comment: @Drewdiddy611, I didn't know that :) But checking the docs, I believe you have to set the recursive option of the containable behavior to true. I mean, is set to true by default, but it's an option also to turn the automatic "recursiveness" (... is that a word?) off.